# Adding prefix to RabbitMQ queues and exchanges in Spring Cloud dataflow backend

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-dataflow

I would like to utilize my own RabbitMQ instance as the middleware broker for Spring Cloud Data Flow.

The problem is that we have a prefix and suffix policy on exchange and queue creation that has to be in place.

Is it possible to force Spring Cloud Data Flow to add this prefix and suffix?

Example:

```
RABBITMQ_QUEUE_PREFIX="TEAM1"
RABBITMQ_QUEUE_SUFFIX="IN"
RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_PREFIX="TEAM1"
RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_SUFFIX="OUT"
```

To result in queues and exchanges:

```
TEAM1.queuename.IN
TEAM1.exchangename.OUT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the prefix at the application level (e.g. in application.properties) or set as a deployer property in SCDF. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_rabbitmq_consumer_properties

Comment: Thanks for the pointer!
I'm not sure if I understand really what to do, but I found this in the documentation you sent.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_using_existing_queuesexchanges

and another stackoverflow that seems to be talking about the same thing.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56378668/3021593

I updates some information in the original question.